How to configure a single log file per scraped address?
When I run a spider, its log file contains information about all the URLs defined in the urls array.
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  custom_settings = {
        'LOG_FILE': f'logs/my_{id}.log',
  }
  
  def start_requests(self):
        
        urls = [
            'https://www.website1.com',
            'https://www.website2.com',
            'https://www.website3.com'
        ]
  ...

Is there a way to configure Scrapy that for every single scraped URL would be generated a single log file? Right now,  I get a log file logs/my_3.log where are all the information from the 3 URLs.
I am trying to get one log file for https://www.website1.com, one for https://www.website2.com and one for https://www.website3.com. Is this possible?

Off the top of my head it's not possible. Also some log lines are not tied to a request.
